# ArcGIS Dashboard

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-online, water, arcgis-water-utilities

I need to make a dashboard that shows proposed mains in our water system. I know I can do this by making a list and setting the lifecycle status to proposed. The problem is that I need another list included in this dashboard to let me know when these proposed mains statuses have changed to active.

Comment: What precisely have you tried so far?  I think your question needs a lot more details before it can be answered.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.